# wso2 - workflow management - 400 Bad Request

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I was trying to configure workflow management as given in the documentation with 5.8.0 version.
The DB used is default H2.

Link followed:
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/workflow-management/
http://cdwijayarathna.blogspot.com/2016/04/making-use-of-wso2-identity-servers.html

When I logged into User Dashboard https://localhost:9443/dashboard nothing is displayed, PFA screenshot in approval section:

Getting 400 Bad request in network as below:

Get API
https://localhost:9443/portal/gadgets/approvals/index.jag?profileList=[object%20Object]

Response: 400 Bad Request

[Bad Request Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdUvl.png)

Here are the users created and user is waiting for approval:

[Waiting for Approval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdUvl.png)

Below are the logs:

```
[2020-06-01 20:39:59,187] approver@abc.com [2] [IS] INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'approver@abc.com [2]' logged in at [2020-06-01 20:39:59,186+0530]
[2020-06-01 21:00:33,938]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2020-06-01 21:00:33,938+0530]
[2020-06-01 21:00:43,044]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged out at [2020-06-01 21:00:43,0043]
[2020-06-01 21:00:54,059] @abc.com [2] [IS] INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager} -  LDAP connection created successfully in read-write mode
[2020-06-01 21:00:54,102] pandry@abc.com [2] [IS] INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'pandry@abc.com [2]' logged in at [2020-06-01 21:00:54,102+0530]
[2020-06-01 21:31:22,815] @abc.com [2] [IS] INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.utils.TenantAxisUtils} -  Starting to clean tenant : abc.com
[2020-06-01 21:31:22,819] @abc.com [2] [IS] INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.Axis2ConfigurationContextObserverImpl} -  Unloading TenantProcessStore for tenant 2.
[2020-06-01 21:31:22,907] @abc.com [2] [IS] INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager} -  LDAP connection created successfully in read-write mode
[2020-06-01 21:31:22,965] @abc.com [2] [IS] INFO {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.Axis2ConfigurationContextObserverImpl} -  Unloading TenantTaskStore for tenant 2.
[2020-06-01 21:31:22,984] @abc.com [2] [IS] INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Removing Axis2 Service: LoginApprovalTaskService {abc.com[2]}
[2020-06-01 21:31:23,016] @abc.com [2] [IS] INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} -  Removing Axis2 Service: userCreateApprovalTaskService {abc.com[2]}
[2020-06-01 21:31:23,028] @abc.com [2] [IS] WARN ***{org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.store.HumanTaskStore} -  Could not find matching AxisService in Tenant AxisConfiguration for service name*** :userCreateApprovalTaskService
[2020-06-01 21:31:23,039] @abc.com [2] [IS] INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.utils.TenantAxisUtils} -  Cleaned up tenant abc.com
```

Comment: Full browser tracer from an Incognito, along with the backend logs might help.

Comment: I have added the logs in question, could you please check.

Answer (score 1):

With more research I found out this is an known issue as mentioned https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/5678 with the change mentioned https://github.com/wso2/product-is/pull/5887/files here